# Not able to parse Decimal number based on locale "el-GR"

Tags: java, locale, number-formatting, decimalformat

I am having trouble understanding this :

```
public static void main(String... arg) {
        //el_GR
//        Locale locale = new Locale("el", "GR");
        Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        NumberFormat numberFormat = DecimalFormat.getInstance(locale);
        try {
            Number value = numberFormat.parse("170.0");
            System.out.println(value.doubleValue());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When using Locale.ENGLISH, it shows 170.0
But when using Greek-Greece, it shows 1700.0

Why does Java fail to parse decimal number for el-GR? Should I define one for this locale?

Updated:
Thanks guys for helping... Apparently I'm not a Greek guy and I'm terrible on math ... ... Will close this question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator first hit on Google. Decimal separator for Greece is `,`

Comment: It doesn't fail to parse, it interprets the `.` as a *thousand-separator*, and ignores it, as it should for the Greek locale.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping. Will close the question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different cultures use different characters as the [decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) and as the [digit grouping delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping). Some use [FULL STOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop) for one, and [COMMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma) for the other. Some, vice versa. Some use a SPACE, or some other character.

A hundred twenty three thousand can appear as either of these, or other formats, depending on cultural norms:

> United States: 123,456.789
>
> Greece: 123.456,789

Greece uses COMMA for decimal separator, and FULL STOP to group digits. So your dot in the input under a Greece locale is being interpreted as a misplaced grouping. Thus 1700 as the result.